# Do I need to use mounted or created?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using VUE. I have to pass an ID from parent component to child component, but when I do that on mounted it just work the first time that the page is rendered, then I call again the child through the button I programed, the ID is null. Do I need to call the method on created() or somethig? How should I code that method (created)?

my code

```
<template> 
  <childComponent :empid="employeeID"> </childComponent> 
</template>

<script>
 ...
 data () {
  return {
    employeeID: null,
 },
 mounted () {
  this.getID()
 },
 methods: {
  getID () {
    this.employeeID = this.params.entity.employee
    // console.log(this.employeeID) // returns null on second time that I called the page
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `this.params.entity.employee` refering to? do you mean to use route params? because then it would be this.$route.params.employee probably

Comment: ``created`` is useful for server side effercts ( calling API) . Use ``watcher`` or ``computed`` properties. To bind your route param with your ID.

Comment: @Dirk V, this.params.entity.employee is refering from another parent component, and I use it as prop in the child= props: ['params'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed property instead:

```
<childComponent :empid="employeeID"> </childComponent>
```

```js
computed: {
  employeeID () {
    return this.params.entity.employee
  }
}
```

Comment: @A.Lau, `fer.trecool` is a new contributor, I don't think he can mark answers as "solved" yet, can he?